# api platform filter with multiple values for the same property

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I'm trying to filter datas using comma separator,

@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"var": "exact"})

Test of /api/test?var[]=2&var[]=3 is OK

but when i tried to filter using comma as separator

/api/test?var[]=2,3

it returns all datas

how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that handles this request? Without seeing what's actually happening, all anyone can do here is make a blind guess.

Comment: Are you after a [range filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#range-filter), [exists filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#exists-filter) or maybe do you need [something custom](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters)?

Comment: ?var[]=2&var[]=3 gives items with var = 2 OR 3. With partial matching you may want other logic, like name = 'John' AND 'Doe' AND NOT 'Doeke'. With [FilterLogic](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/filter-bundle) this can be done with ?and[name][]=John&and[name][]=Doe&and[not][name]=Doeke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can set values like that in a query string.

When you write `var[]=2,3` you are setting the value of the first element of the variable to 2,3. It is equivalent to this:

`$var[0] = '2,3';`

When you write a query string like this `var[]=2&var[]=3` it is equivalent to:

`$var[0] = '2'; $var[1] = '3';`

If you write a custom handler for the route in api platform, then you could split the value once you have retrieved it from the query string:

```
$var[0] = '2,3';
$arrayOfValues = explode( ',', $var[0] );
```

What is the reason that you want to structure your query string differently?